# redirect typed-in url to new url BUT using some of typed-in data

Tags: php, url

What I want to achieve is the following:

I want people to be able to type in this: http://www.myurl.com/12

although this url doesn't really exist, and then make sure they are redirected to a correct url but still keep the 1 at the end of the entered url in a variable or something.

The goal is to enable people enter a short url like: http://www.myurl.com/12
and still have them ending up on the right page, and seeing the content that corresponds to the content with number 12

any suggestions?
I don;t need fully elaborated answers, just a suggestion on where to look

thanks a lot
Sam

Comment: My host doesn't provide apache rewrite; i;ve checked with them.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be possible to write a script that takes the user entered url, uses the relevant part of that entered url, and redirects to a more complex url ... so for instance, a user enters myurl.com/x, a page that doesn't exist, but some script will take that x, and redirects to an url using that x: myurl/allkindofstuff?somevar=x

Answer (score 0):

You can look at URL rewrites for Apache/Nginx or location handling in Nginx. This is mostly a configuration for your webserver, which is probably Apache.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)$  index.php?number=$1
```

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Alright, I must admit I;m not very familiar with this. I've emailed my host to ask if they can set this for me, or is this something I should do in a certain file? thx

Comment: Maybe they can, if they provide this support. Who is your host? Sometimes they have guides on doing this. You should have access to editing these files. If it is powered by Apache, you can use a file called `.htaccess` located in the root htdocs or public_html folder